# Building up a string result in String Compression

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic

I am having difficulties for formulating a possible solution, for a question called string compression where I need to compress a string based on repeating characters

INPUT: aabbccddeeff
OUTPUT a2b2c2d2e2f2

INPUT: abbbccddeeff
OUTPUT: a1b3c2d2e2f2

My code currently is able to identify repeating characters(I will implement logic for non repeating characters soon)

**My question is**
How would I input the amount of times a character appears, i am thinking of using an empty string and dynamically building up a solution however this is proving to be relatively difficult

My code

```
*public static void strCompression(String word){
     char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
     int idx = 0;
     int jdx = idx + 1;
     int times = 0;
     String empt = "";
     while (idx<arr.length)
     {
         while(jdx != arr.length)
         {
             if(arr[idx] == arr[jdx])
             {
                 times = (jdx - idx) + 1;
                  
             }
              idx = jdx;
             ++jdx;
         }
         ++idx;
     }
     
}*
```

Can someone give me some guidance on how i would go about doing this.

Also in my code snippet, index i gets index j if there is not duplicate elements, it then starts counting to check if there are any other duplicate elements. so for example

aaaaabbbbb

pointer is idx is at 0 which is a, jdx counts how many times a occurs, when index at i is not equal to index at j(different char values) then we will set the index at i to be equal to index at j

Should this be idx = jdx + 1 or idx = jdx;

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pointer is idx is at 0 which is a, jdx counts how many times a occurs, when index at i is not equal to index at j(different char values) then we will set the index at i to be equal to index at j

Yeah, `idx = jdx` is correct.

**Logic:**

You have implemented it until getting the frequency of an element.

So moving on to the next part,

1. whenever you receive a different element, you need to add that element with to `empt` and change the indices accordingly and exit the inner `while loop` .

```java
// if element is same change the times accordingly
if(arr[idx] == arr[jdx])
 {
     times = (jdx - idx) + 1;
      
 }

// if different add to empt and change idx and jdx accordingly
else {
    empt += arr[idx];
    empt += times.toString();
    times = 1;
    idx = jdx;
    jdx++;
    break;
}
```

2. Still something more to do, because the above code will not handle the case if we don't enter the `else statement` ( this happens when last element is unique (or) same is its previous elements) i.e basically to handle the last element.

```java
while (idx < len)
{
     while(jdx != len)
     {
        ...
     }

     if (jdx == len) {
        times = (jdx - idx);
        empt += arr[idx];
        empt += times.toString();
        break;
     }
}
```

**Full Code:**

```java
int times = 1; // if the first element appears only once
while (idx < len)
{
     while(jdx != len)
     {

         if(arr[idx] == arr[jdx])
         {
             times = (jdx - idx) + 1;
              
         }

         else {
            empt += arr[idx];
            empt += times.toString();
            times = 1; // resetting times = 1
            idx = jdx;
            jdx++;
            break;
         }
        ++jdx;
     }

     if (jdx == len) {
        times = (jdx - idx);
        empt += arr[idx];
        empt += times.toString();
        break;
     }
}
```

**Note:**

There is some redundancy here, like updating the `times` everytime you encounter a same element, so I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: I have tried this code, however it did not work on a case such as this 
"bbbbbbccceeee"

Output: b6c2 

it is suppose to b6c3e4 

i understand your code logic, but for some reason it wont work after the c character

Comment: Thanks so much, time for me to understand what you have done :)

Comment: The code does not work for cases such as "a" it should be a1 not a0